# Why are my cherry tomato sprout’s leaves yellowing and getting brown/gray spots?

Tags: identification, plant-health, leaves, watering, tomatoes

This is my first year trying to grow cherry tomatoes from seeds in my raised garden bed. My 2 month old tomato sprout was looking super healthy until last week or so and it started getting yellowing leaves with small brown/gray spots on the older leaves but it’s pretty quickly spreading to the newer growth leaves as well. I live in Alabama, the bed gets about 8+ hours of direct sunlight, I water once a day first thing in the morning, unless it rained recently. It was planted in Miracle Grow Garden Soil for vegetables and herbs. Am I over watering? Or is there some other issue? I initially thought the cause was a plant vitamin foliar  spray I was using called Super Thrive which is 0.005% nitrogen and derived from kelp. But I stopped using this and leaves that I don’t think were ever sprayed are also getting the spots now.

[1]: [image]

Edit:
I think I figured it out, if anyone else comes across this question here’s what I did: I did more research and decided the reason was probably nutrition deficiency since we just used the potting mix for the initial planting and then had not fertilized since because the bag said it would feed plants for 3 months. I added Epsom salt, since it seems we should have done this from the start, and then mixed in a balanced pellet fertilizer. Well sho enough, this little guy is looking way better a week later! So it was most definitely not the nitrogen foliar spray, and in fact, I should have been applying this more often.

[image]